# Comprehending the Bubble Sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Stack Overflow
I was looking into algorithms so I could break them down piece by piece to understand what is going on. Anyways, I was looking at [this](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Bubble_sort) tutorial to look into the bubble sort. I was confused by a very small part of the demonstration algorithm in C++, the integer j.

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) {
  bool swapped = true;
  int j = 0;
  int tmp;
  while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++) {
              if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                    tmp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = tmp;
                    swapped = true;
              }
        }
  }
}
```

Is it a required part of the algorithm? I don't really understand what it's doing, as when I swapped j inside the for loop for 1, I got the same results.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
```

TL;DR:
Why is the int j in the algorithm?

Comment: @downvoters: care to leave a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first outer iteration, we would bubble down the largest integer into `a[n-1]`. The second iteration only needs to traverse the remaining unsorted part of the array i.e. from index 0 to n-2 and bubble down the second largest integer into `a[n-2]`. The third iteration only needs to traverse array from index 0 to n-3, and so on.

Variable `j` achieves this by limiting the range of array to traverse in subsequent outer iterations. We can very well traverse the entire array in every iteration (as you would do after changing `n-j` with `n-1`) and obtain the same result. But that would be inefficient, since we would unnecessarily be comparing elements in sorted part of array in every iteration. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

As bubblesort works it's way up the list, it swaps the bigger number to the end of the list. This means that with every iteration of the algorithm the last elements are guaranteed to be sorted. If the last elements are sorted, there is no point to revisiting them to sort them again. `n-j` prevents this by restricting the range of the list to be visited on any iteration. If `j` grows as the algorithm proceeds, `n-j` contracts.

Rather than just looking at the code, fire it up in [the debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that almost certainly came with your development environment (and if you don't have a development environment with a debugger it's long past time you corrected this. The debugger is possibly the greatest productivity tool the working programmer has) and step through the code. Watch what happens to the list and the range of the list visited on each iteration.

The debugger is not just a great tool for fixing code, it can be a great educational tool as well.

Comment: I second the debugger advocacy

Answer (score 0):

The j variable is used to move the largest number towards the right. On every iteration we move the pointer from n (initially n-j=n as j is 0) to 0 by step 1. Finally we have a sorted array.

Comment: I understand this, but I don't understand why the variable j needs to increment every iteration?